# Why was my duplicate flag declined?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicates, flagging

I tagged [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140674) as a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105549) yet my flag was declined. The question has now been marked as a duplicate of that question, so why was my flag declined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look at the timeline of the post to see what happened.

It was declined automatically when the review queue vote result ended up as “Leave Open” (by 3 to 1). Your flag recommended it for duplication, but the reviewers disagreed. That ended the recommendation with a “decline.”

Later a user with a gold badge closed it as a duplicate.

Though the outcome seems weird, it’s not really that odd when opinions are divided. Getting to the right end result can sometimes take a few iterations.

(One declined flag isn’t a black mark on your account either, so don’t worry too much about that.)